# Why are builds from one developer not evaluating the Maven profile activation expression properly?

Tags: java, maven

I work on the platform for a large number of Maven-built services.  Quite a few of them have a construct like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
            <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
            <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
            <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>!windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
```

For now, I'm not including the entire pom.xml.  I might if no one can get a clue with what I've provided so far.

The important part is the end of that listing.  That last profile should only activate if the OS is NOT Windows.  I work on Windows, and another developer I work with is also on Windows. We also have many other developers working on Windows, and also Macs, but that one developer on Windows is having a problem with this pom.xml.

When I run a build using this, it correctly does NOT execute the plugins in that activation block, because I am on Windows. When that other developer executes this, and we've tried with Maven 3.9.1 and 3.8.8 (I'm testing with 3.8.8), it executes the plugins in that block, and fails because of that (it specifies steps that will not work on Windows).

I have carefully pored over the "mvn -X" output from both me and him (which I'm not providing as of yet), and I certainly see where his output executes those plugins and mine does not, but I don't see any obvious "decision point" where it evaluates that expression and decides to activate that profile.

What I'm looking for are some leads.  What should I look for in differences between his output and mine?

**Update**:

If it helps, the output of the enforcer plugin is shown at the top of our "mvn -X" output, so I'll post that here.  There are only two small differences between his and mine.

Mine:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.8 (4c87b05d9aedce574290d1acc98575ed5eb6cd39)
Maven home: ...\apache-maven-3.8.8
Java version: 11.0.13, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

His:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.8 (4c87b05d9aedce574290d1acc98575ed5eb6cd39)
Maven home: ...\apache-maven-3.8.8
Java version: 11.0.18, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

We're using slightly different patch versions of Java 11, and for some reason his OS name is "windows 11", whereas mine is "windows 10". Everything else is the same.

Comment: Are there any other activation conditions other than the os?

Comment: Also, is your colleague using WSL by any chance? What's the output of `mvn enforcer:display-info` in his machine?

Comment: Despite the fact that I'm not showing the entire pom.xml, I did show the entire start of the profiles block, that shows the only activation conditions. I'll queue up a request for him to run that mvn command, and I'll inspect the output and compare it with mine. Oh, looking at the output of that, I already have that. I'll update the post with that. He is not using WSL.

Comment: Find that bit of code in maven and put a breakpoint there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems that his slightly newer version of JDK actually reports the correct version of the operating system. According to Java [bug report JDK-8274737](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8274737) that was fixed in version 11.0.13 and included in the [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-13-relnotes.html) but the version that you are using for some reason doesn't seem to contain the fix and it is mentioned again in the [release notes of Java 11.0.1](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-14-relnotes.html)4. Since that is the only apparent difference you should try with a newer version of Java 11.

Comment: I'm confused. My coworker, who is using 11.0.18 is who is having the problem. I am using the older 11.0.13, which is not seeing the problem. Are you saying that if I upgrade to 11.0.18, I will start seeing the same problem?

Comment: I missread who had the issue. My assumption is that the only components that seem different are Maven version and operating system. You should also try with latest Maven version and Java version.